# Task inheritance in gulp, parent gulpfile.js

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I am using node/gulp to run/build my projects. Accross those projects my gulpfiles look very similar. Since I'm coming from a Java/Maven background I was looking for sth. like a parent gulpfile one could inherit basic tasks from (this is easily possible with a parent pom.xml in maven).

Is this somehow build into gulp, are there modules doing this or do I need to figure this myself?

I could think of having a node module doing nothing else then providing basic gulp tasks that one can require from his dependent gulp file. Any experiences on an approach like this?

BR
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just export the `gulp` object in your parent gulpfile and then require it in the child gulpfiles:

**project/gulpfile.js:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('commontask', function () { });

module.exports = gulp;
```

**project/subproject/gulpfile.js:**

```
var gulp = require('../gulpfile.js');

gulp.task('subtask', [ 'commontask' ], function() { });
```

Running `subtask` from the `project/subproject` directory:

```
> gulp subtask
[12:38:05] Using gulpfile ~/project/subproject/gulpfile.js
[12:38:05] Starting 'commontask'...
[12:38:05] Finished 'commontask' after 50 μs
[12:38:05] Starting 'subtask'...
[12:38:05] Finished 'subtask' after 20 μs
```

---

**EDIT:** The above won't work if the parent gulpfile isn't part of the same package (e.g. `my-app`) but rather from another package  that you depend on (e.g. `my-common-tasks`). The reason is that the way module loading in Node.js works, you end up with two instances of `gulp`: one in `my-common-tasks` and one in `my-app`. Your tasks will be defined in the instance from `my-common-tasks`, but the `gulp` CLI will look for the tasks in the instance from `my-app`.

Instead you have to pass the `gulp` instance from `my-app` to `my-common-tasks`:

**my-common-tasks/gulpfile.js**:

```
module.exports = function(gulp) {
  gulp.task('common-task', function () { });
};
```

**my-app/gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
require('my-common-tasks')(gulp);

gulp.task('sub-task', [ 'common-task' ], function() { });
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of. But my projects are physically separated. That's why I was thinking of packaging the 'parent' gulpfile into a simple node module, use it as dependency in the subprojects und load the parent gulp tasks from node_modules. Does that sound like a solid solution to you?

Comment: You can also load the data from node environment variables. It would be easy as well.